# Build of Hadoop on Windows: branch-1-win

Tags: windows, hadoop

Has anyone published a non-proprietary (ie not Hortonworks/Cloudera/Greenplum) Apache Hadoop distribution based on the `branch-1-win` branch of the `hadoop-common` code repository? Alternatively, has anyone been able to build this branch on a Mac?

I'm trying to get *vanilla* Apache Hadoop to work on Windows, without faffing with Cygwin. All of the fixes seem to have been made, as Hortonworks have backported them to their distribution, and the branch is full of all the applied patches. I'm struggling to get the build to work (a plethora of issues, too numerous to raise SO's for!), so I'm really hoping someone else has a functioning build they've published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must build `branch-1-win` on Windows. It requires use of the MSBuild tool, which comes package with .NET 4 or Visual Studio C++. You will also need Ant, Python 2.7, Perl and Apache Forrest.